# AWS Glue: Force crawler to not create partitions based on S3 subfolders in table

Tags: aws-glue

I have data structured as follows:

```
s3://project/vehicle1/tbl_vehicle1_speeddata/trip00000001/00000001.parquet
s3://project/vehicle1/tbl_vehicle1_speeddata/trip00000001/00000002.parquet
...
s3://project/vehicle1/tbl_vehicle1_speeddata/trip00000002/00000001.parquet
```

I'm currently using AWS Glue to prepare this data for querying via Athena. I wish to create a separate table for the message level, i.e. a table would e.g. be `tbl_vehicle1_speeddata`.

I would like to retain the grouping of parquet files by trip as in the structure. This is how my original hardware structures the data and it ensures that the files within the trip folders can overlap with the filenames of other trip folders. In other words, the trip folder level purely serves as an S3 folder structure that makes it easy to work with the data in other tools (MATLAB, Python, ...).

However, AWS Glue seems to enforce the creation of a `partition_0` column in my tables, which refers to the name of the trip subfolder level for each table. In itself, this could be ignored, but the problem is that it implies that AWS Glue needs to be run everytime we wish to be able to query data from new trips - even though the underlying parquet files are identical in schema structure.

What I would like to do is to keep my S3 structure - but force AWS Glue to not automatically create partitions based on the S3 path - but this appears to not be possible?

Any guidance on how this can be achieves would be great. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this via a simple setting in the console, but if that is not possible then perhaps via the boto3 API.

It is not an option for me to 'manually' edit the schema of every new table as these are dynamically created and use different schemas.